# why delay is not available in gcc

Tags: c, linux

Why delay is not available in gcc? As per my understanding delay function halt the program while sleep function make program to sleep and perform context switching. If I want to halt my program what is the available option in gcc?

Comment: You want to prevent context switching? As in to bring down the machine? You simply need to `sleep` on a non-multitasking OS. Linux won't do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [implement time delay in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930363/implement-time-delay-in-c) (At least, as much as I can decipher the question)

Comment: @Potatoswatter I want system to halt ...Its my program requirement

Comment: @Brian Roach the thread you pointed also using sleep and time functions which are making context switching...

Comment: You might want to say why or what kind of program would have such a requirement. Typically that would be the definition of a very hard crash.

Comment: Program requirement I mentioned in comment of below Answer. Anyhow I also want to know the answer for WHY as well.

Comment: use algorithm like: `now=time(); later=now+60; while(time() <= later) asm("nop");`

Comment: If you want to "halt" the program, you can let one thread sleep() and another thread burn away CPU in a loop, waiting for the sleeper thread to wake up. Why you would ever want to do such a weird thing, I have no idea. There is never a guarantee that a context switch won't happen at any place in your program. Linux is not a RTOS.

Answer (score 5):

Because `delay` is, as far as I know, not in the C99 or C2011 standard.

The C standard is quite poor on APIs (it mostly knows about `FILE*`, some memory operations like `malloc`, a few string operations, and `setjmp` ...; it does not know about directories or delays).

Context switching does not make sense in pure standard C. (it only makes sense on multi-tasked operating systems à la Unix).

A delay function should be provided by the (non-standard-C) programming environment. On Linux, it is a superset of Posix which indeed have [sleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) and many other functions. You could use [sched_yield(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) syscall to "force" a context switch.

You should **read some book like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)**. Perhaps to stop the system you want to use the [sync(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sync.2.html) and [reboot(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/reboot.2.html) syscalls, but this is probably a bad idea; you probably want to run, e.g. with `system(3)`, the `shutdown` or `halt` command.

If you just want to stop your particular program (and let the rest of the system run other processes as usual), simply call [exit(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exit.3.html) which *is* in the C standard.

PS. If you write a kernel device driver you should state that explicitly in the question and you really should learn a lot more about Linux. Inside some driver you might call some panic function when in deep trouble.

Comment: He wants to *prevent* a context switch. `sched_yield` has the same effect as `sleep` in that regard. "Solving" his problem involves leaving Linux entirely, or running the program in the kernel.

Comment: Agreed, and I did wrote that `sched_yield` will force a context switch. Actually, I have the strange feeling that the original poster *Mustafa* does not understand Linux, and will have a lot of trouble if he does not learn more....

Comment: And even if `delay` was in the C Standard, you would find it in the libc and not in `gcc`.

Comment: I am writing a device driver. During two read or write operations system should halt for few second....

Comment: A device driver runs inside the kernel. It is not a C program (it often is a kernel module). Technically the entire kernel is a freestanding implementation and does not follow the usual C standard. But before writing any driver, you should learn a big lot about Linux (read several books, be fluent with application level system programming....).

Comment: Basile - excellent response to a regrettable question. Sincere kudos.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `sleep()` then OS promptly switch context. Doesn't this behaviour satisfy you? In other words, do you want to hold CPU and do nothing for a given period? Then do busy_waiting; `for(; ; ;) break_if_time_elapses`. Even then, you cannot escape time-slice based context switching by OS. So it's meaningful for very short time, less than OS's time slice.

Comment: thanks cwyang this could be an option but how to impose some specified amount of time for example halt for 3 sec.

Comment: Inside the kernel you cannot stop for 3 seconds. If you did that, you could physically **break the hardware** (e.g. because some fans would not be active).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch thanks for your help. I think I need to learn alot :(

Comment: No you need to learn a very big lot. That means months of learning. Don't play inside the kernel till you are not fluent with application level system programming.